# unix find a single file thats updated recently when there are duplicate files with the same name

Tags: unix, find

I am using the find command below to find and list 'test.txt' in more than one dir.

As you can see output, i am getting more than one result as there are duplicate files under various sub dirs which is perfectly ok.

Now, i have to pick up only the file that updated recently.

I know i can use -mtime to pick up files modified in last hour or day.

But i dont know when the file was modififed. I just need the file that was updated most recently out of all the duplicates.

can you please help?

command:

```
find source_feeds-20170101* -name test.txt -exec ls -ltr {} \;
```

output:

```
 -rw-r----- 1 user123 group1 87841 May 27 10:46 source_feeds-20170101_1/test.txt

 -rw-r----- 1 user123 group1 87841 May 20 7:25 source_feeds-20170101_2/test.txt
```

Comment: look at output of `stat path/2/yourFile`. But it may be that even resolution of `Change: 2017-05-31 07:22:01.975329001` will "tie" (Unlikely I guess). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
find source_feeds-20170101* -name test.txt -exec ls -ltr {} + | tail -1
```

If you using + instead of ;/ at the end of the find will solve the issue.
;/ execute `ls -ltr path1 ; ls -ltr path2` one by one while + is execute `ls -ltr path1 path2 path3` this will generate only one output instead of one output by match.

Answer (score 0):

The below worked for me.

```
find source_feeds-20170101* -name test.txt -print0 | xargs -0 ls -ltr | tail -1
```

Comment: I misunderstand the question at first look. Sorry about that you could make this sorter and faster by removing xargs , -print0 and use `-exec ls -ltr {} +` I updated my answer as well.